# Jquery resize iframe that changes

Tags: jquery, iframe, window-resize

I have code that resizes an iframe pretty well. The only problem is that it adjusts to the new size immediately and doesn't account for transition time. As a result, any divs that expand with transition time force the iframe to cut off the bottom of my document. I'm REALLY new to jquery so I don't know how to add a timer to this code I found.

```
function resizeFrame(ctrl) {

    $(ctrl.contentWindow.document).ready(function ()
    {
        var s;
        s = 100;
        ctrl.style.height = s;
        var doc = $(ctrl.contentWindow.document);

        s = doc.height() + "px";
        ctrl.style.height = s;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//FOR A DELAY

```
function resizeFrame(ctrl) {

    $(ctrl.contentWindow.document).ready(function ()
    {

var myDelay = setTimeout(resizeMe, 2500); //2 1/2 second delay

function resizeMe(){
        var s;
        s = 100;
        ctrl.style.height = s;
        var doc = $(ctrl.contentWindow.document);

        s = doc.height() + "px";
        ctrl.style.height = s;
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a delay, you can use `setTimeout`.  If you need a gradual size change, then look into the jQuery animation tools.

Comment: I think that would work but I don't know where to put it in the code since I'm so new to jquery.